# SuiteScript 2 load library first

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Hi and thanks I need to make sure that a specific library is loaded first in SuiteScript 2.0 scripts. Doesn't matter which type of script I am running. The library contains polyfills that other scripts need to use. Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help you may give.

Comment: I would just have every module that depends on it explicitly pull in the library module itself. Modules don't execute until all of their dependencies are loaded. require.js should take care of any duplicate loads.

Comment: Hi and thanks, Do you mean just adding it to the define statement? In that case, these libraries are not set up in that way, they are not AMD/requirejs. These are third-party libraries. The libraries have ES6 language aspects that I need to polyfill. So the polyfill needs to be loaded before the target script, thanks for any help.

Comment: In what context/script types are you running these scripts?

Comment: it could be anything, scheduled, userevent, mass-update etc, currently right now I am just worrying about, @erictgrubaugh actually was close. I found today that I can use a package called babel to compile the offensive libraries and through configuration detail what language level I wanted. It will go through the code and rewrite it taking out the offensive features and writing them in the older version of Javascript. I just point it at a folder of the libraries I need to convert and away it goes. it will also add the defines and the requireds. So this was the answer and it works well

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks to everyone for your help. As usual, @erictgrubaugh was on the money, I found a package called Babel that will compile your scripts down to whatever version you need. It will also add the defines and requirements if you need them, you can pick the module type to support. So I got it up and running and it seems fine. Once again thanks, everyone.